# Using XPath to get complete text of paragraph with span inside

Tags: xpath

```
<ul>
  <li class="xyz">
    <div class="divClass">
      <span class="ContentItem---status---dL0iS">
        <span>Success</span>
      </span>
      <p class="ContentItem---title---37IqA">
        <span>Test Check</span>
        : Please display the text
      </p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="xyz">
    <div class="divClass">
      <span class="ContentItem---status---dL0iS">
    <span>Not COMPLETED</span>
      </span>
      <p class="ContentItem---title---37IqA">
        <span>Knowledge</span> A Team
      </p>
    </div>
  </li>
  .... and so on
</ul>
```

This is my html structure.I have this text `Test Check` inside a Span and `: Please display the text` inside a Paragraph tag. 
What i need is ,i need to identify, whether my structure contains this complete text or not `Test Check: Please display the text`.

I have tried multiple ways and couldn't identify the complete path.Please find the way which i have tried
`//span[text()='Test Check']/p[text()=': Please display the text']`
Can you please provide me the xpath for this?

Comment: Try this one `//span[.="Success"]/following-sibling::p/normalize-space()`

Comment: Try `//p[normalize-space() = 'TestCheck : Please display the text ']` or `//p[span = 'Test Check' and text()[normalize-space() = ' : Please display the text ']]`

Answer (score 0):

I think there is one possible solution to identify within the given html text and retrieve. I hope this solves your problem.

```
def get_tag_if_present(html_text):
    soup_obj = BeautifulSoup(html_text,"html.parser")
    test_check = soup_obj.find_all(text = re.compile(r"Test Check"))
    result_val = "NOT FOUND"
    if test_check:
        for each_value in test_check:
            parent_tag_span = each_value.parent
            if parent_tag_span.name == "span":
                parent_p_tag = parent_tag_span.parent
                if parent_p_tag.name == "p" and "Please display the text" in parent_p_tag.get_text():
                    result_val = parent_p_tag
                    break
    return result_val
```

The returned result_val will have the tag corresponding to the p tag element with the parameter. It would return NOT FOUND, if no such element exists.
I've taken this with the assumption that the corresponding data entries would exist in a "p" tag and "span" tag respectively , feel free to remove the said conditions for all identifications of the text in the given html text.